# Why my code doesn't quit after termination when invoked by xfce4 desktop?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I have this python code:

```
#: #!/bin/python3
import sys
from gi.repository import Gtk
if sys.stdin.isatty() :
      print('not a tty')
      quit()
sel=sys.stdin.read()
def action1(self):
   print(sel.upper())
   Gtk.main_quit()
def action2(self):
   print(sel.lower())
   Gtk.main_quit()
def action3(self):
   print(sel[0].upper()+sel[1:].lower())
   Gtk.main_quit()
def action4(self):
   if '?' in sel:
        print('¿'+sel)
   if '!' in sel:
        print('¿'+sel)
   if '¡' in sel:
        print('¿'+sel)
   if ')' in sel:
        print('('+sel)
   if '"' in sel:
        print('"'+sel)
   if "\'" in sel:
        print("\'"+sel)
   Gtk.main_quit()

def show_menu( *args):
    i1 = Gtk.MenuItem("Mayúsculas")
    i1.connect("activate" , action1)
    i1.connect("activate" , Gtk.main_quit)
    menu.append(i1)

    i2 = Gtk.MenuItem("Minúsculas")
    i2.connect("activate" , action2)
    i2.connect("activate" , Gtk.main_quit)
    menu.append(i2)

    i3 = Gtk.MenuItem("Mayús, inicial")
    i3.connect("activate" , action3)
    i3.connect("activate" , Gtk.main_quit)
    menu.append(i3)


    i4 = Gtk.MenuItem("Abrir sección")
    i4.connect("activate" , action4)
    i4.connect("activate" , Gtk.main_quit)
    menu.append(i4)
    menu.show_all()
    menu.popup(None, None, None, None, 0, Gtk.get_current_event_time())
#    print("Done")

menu = Gtk.Menu()
menu.connect('destroy',Gtk.main_quit)
show_menu()
Gtk.main()
#quit()
```

It's intended to be a utility to convert text, the problem is that when I run it through a hotkey inside of my xfce4 desktop it remains iddle and never exits. I'm really inexpert using gtk and I have no clue what I am doing wrong, can you help me please??????